# Fetch React server components from client component

Tags: reactjs, react-server-components

I was thinking about fetching a server component client side after an interaction without using the url of the entire page. It looks doable since React can asynchronously hydrate partial component trees.

I'm not looking for neither injecting a server component in the page as usual, nor using dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Imagine an endpoint "/components/foo" which renders a server component and returns a RSC json format.
Here is an example to illustrate that, i don't know how InjectServerComponent should work.

```js
function ClientComponent() {
  const [fooData, setFooData] = useState(null)

  const onClick = async () => {
     const fooData = await fetch(`/components/foo`)
     setFooData(fooData)
  }

  return (
   <>
     <button onClick={onClick}>Inject server component</button>
     <InjectServerComponent data={fooData} />
   <>
  )
}
```